# Null Dependency Injection in .NET Maui

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI application and facing an issue where my CourseViewModel is being injected as null into my CoursesPage. I am using the built-in dependency injection in .NET MAUI and have registered my ViewModel and services in the MauiProgram class.

ViewModel Code:

```
    using AcademicPlanner.CoreEntities;
using AcademicPlanner.Pages;
using AcademicPlanner.UseCases.Interface;
using AcademicPlanner.Views;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace AcademicPlanner.ViewModel
{
    public partial class CourseViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        private readonly ICourseUseCases _courseUseCases;
        private readonly ITermUseCases _termUseCases;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public ObservableCollection<Course> courseCollection;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string text;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public Term selectedTerm;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public Course selectedCourse;
        [ObservableProperty]
        public string pageTitle;

        public CourseViewModel(ICourseUseCases useCases, ITermUseCases termUseCase)
        {
            _courseUseCases = useCases;
            _termUseCases = termUseCase;
            courseCollection = new ObservableCollection<Course>();
            PageTitle = SelectedTerm.TermTitle + " Courses";
        }

        public async Task SetSelectedTerm(int termId)
        {
            SelectedTerm = await _termUseCases.ExecuteGetTermByIdAsync(termId);
        }

        public async Task SetSelectedCourse(int courseId)
        {
            SelectedCourse = await _courseUseCases.ExecuteGetCourseByIdAsync(courseId);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Delete(Course course)
        {
            await _courseUseCases.ExecuteRemoveAsync(course);
            await LoadCoursesAsync();
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Tap(string s)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(CoursesPage)}?Text={s}");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Add()
        {
            if (Text == null)
                return;

            Course newCourse = new Course();
            newCourse.TermId = SelectedTerm.TermId;
            newCourse.Name = Text;
            newCourse.StartDate = DateTime.Now;
            newCourse.EndDate = DateTime.Now;
            newCourse.InstructorName = "Instructor Name";
            newCourse.InstuctorEmail = "instuctro@wgu.edu";
            newCourse.InstuctorPhone = "111-111-1111";
            await _courseUseCases.ExecuteAddAsync(newCourse);
            Text = "";
            await LoadCoursesAsync();
        }

        public async Task LoadCoursesAsync()
        {
            if (SelectedTerm == null) return;

            CourseCollection.Clear();
            var buffer = await _courseUseCases.ExecuteGetCoursesByTermIdAsync(SelectedTerm.TermId);

            if (buffer == null) return;
            foreach (Course course in buffer)
            {
                CourseCollection.Add(course);
            }
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task GoToAssesments()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(AssesmentsPage));
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task ToggleEditMode(Course course)
        {
            string s = course.CourseId.ToString();
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(EditCoursePage)}?courseId={s}");
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        public async Task UpdateCourseAsync()
        {
            await _courseUseCases.ExecuteUpdateAsync(SelectedCourse);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
        }
    }
}
```

Page Code:

```
[QueryProperty(nameof(termIdString), "termId")]
public partial class CoursesPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly CourseViewModel _courseViewModel;

    public CoursesPage(CourseViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _courseViewModel = vm;
        BindingContext = _courseViewModel;
        _= _courseViewModel.SetSelectedTerm(TermId);
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await _courseViewModel.LoadCoursesAsync();
    }

    public int TermId { get; set; }

    public string termIdString
    {
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value) && int.TryParse(value, out int termID))
            {
                TermId = termID;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MauiProgram Class:

```
namespace AcademicPlanner
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder.UseMauiApp<App>().ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

            builder.UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
            /*
             * These register classes and interface mappings with .NET Maui, so that it can automatically create
             * instances for dependency injection at runtime.
             */
            //Views
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<TermsPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<CoursesPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<AssesmentsPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<EditTermPage>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<EditCoursePage>();

            // View Models
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<TermViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<CourseViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<AssesmentViewModel>();

            //Interface mappings
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITermUseCases, TermUseCases>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISQLiteRepository, SqlTermRepository>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICourseUseCases, CourseUseCases>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISQLiteCourses, SqlCourseRepository>();
#if DEBUG
            builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Issue:

When navigating to CoursesPage using GoToAsync, the constructor of CoursesPage gets called, but the vm parameter is null. This causes a NullReferenceException when I go to the page.

What I Have Tried:

- Confirmed that the MauiProgram class is correctly executed and the services are registered.
- Ensured that CoursesPage does not have multiple constructors.
- Checked for any issues with the ViewModel's dependencies (ICourseUseCases and ITermUseCases) and confirmed they are also registered with the DI container.
- Removed the injection from the page (And then I could navigate to the page)
  Question:

What might be causing the CourseViewModel to be injected as null and how can I resolve this issue? The error is just "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I am at a loss, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you set up a test service that receives just that dependency, dos it resolve correctly?

Comment: Perhaps adding `Debug.WriteLine()` in all your constructors will help you troubleshoot which constructors are being invoked (and which aren't).

Comment: @stuartd I did and get the same result when I try to inject it into the page.

Comment: @StephenQuan Yeah, its not calling the CourseViewModel constructor. Can't figure out why.

Comment: Well the usual troubleshooting steps to try would be, try swapping out the construction injection parameters but instantiate your depdencies instead with with the ServiceHelper/ServiceProvider class: https://github.com/davidortinau/WeatherTwentyOne/blob/main/src/WeatherTwentyOne/Services/ServiceExtensions.cs

Comment: The issue was trying to use the SelectedTerm in the CourseViewModel constructor.